# How to escape # in the redirect_uri for OAuth2?

Tags: oauth2, developer-console, oauth, developer, developer-org

I am redirecting user to salesforce for OAuth. It is giving me the error that unsupported response_type. When i debugged in the detail then i found that it is due to `#` in the url.

How can i escape #? I tried %23 but it didnt work.

[https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=https://example.com/#/salesforce/callback&response_type=code&state={state}](https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&redirect_uri=https://example.com/#/salesforce/callback&response_type=code&state=%7Bstate%7D)